# Super constructor in cdef classes

Tags: constructor, cython, subclass

I am working on wrapping a C library using cython. I would like to use a `cdef class` to wrap a simple struct. The struct does require some parameters to be properly initialized. I put the corresponding code int the `__cinit__` method like so:

```
cdef class Func:
    cdef library.Func* func

def __cinit__(self, int value):
    library.init_func(&self.func, value)
```

In python code I can create a function object via `f = Func(17)`. The code then handles the initialization just fine. My question is the following: Say I want to extend the `Func` class in python (`class MyFunc(Func): ...`). How do I add a constructor to to `MyFunc`?

I would like to write a constructor with other parameters which calls
`__cinit__(self, int value)` with a value derived from constructor parameters. But it does not seem to be possible (likely for good reason) to call `__cinit__` from python code.

Is there some way to include constructors in subclasses or should I create a wrapper around the function and delegate methods / properties?

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#initialisation-methods-cinit-and-init says "If you need to pass a modified argument list to the base type, you will have to do the relevant part of the initialisation in the __init__() method instead (where the normal rules for calling inherited methods apply)."